# Invert json.loads by json.dumps leads to TypeError: Object of type SimpleNamespace is not JSON serializable

Tags: json

I want to replace some parts in a json.
More specifically: I want to increase the value dict.zone1.heat.target.high by 5. I have found some similiar problems and solutions, but they do not match my problem.

```
`myjson = '{"zone1":{"heat":{"target":{"high":35,"low":25},"outside":{"high":15,"low":-15}}}}'
print(myjson)
# Parse JSON into an object with attributes corresponding to dict keys.
dict = json.loads(myjson, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
dict.zone1.heat.target.high += 5
output = json.dumps(dict)
print(output)`
```

The code above leads to this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type SimpleNamespace is not JSON serializable
```

I tried to google the error, but did not find and hints that helped me. I guess json.dumps needs more arguments to convert correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Types generated by using `SimpleNamespace` are not JSON.

In order to get a JSON-compatible object, you need to access the `__dict__` property of an object (which will looks something like: `{"a_key":"a_value","b_key":"b_value"}`

When you are dealing with embedded objects, you need to access the `__dict__` for each embedded objects. Fortunately, you can provide `json.dump` with a custom JSON Serializer Function. So, when it doesn't know how to directly transform the object to JSON, it will call it.

```
def get_obj_dict(obj):
    return obj.__dict__

myjson = '{"zone1":{"heat":{"target":{"high":35,"low":25},"outside":{"high":15,"low":-15}}}}'

data = json.loads(myjson, object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))
jsonString = json.dumps(data, default=get_obj_dict)
print(jsonString)
```